# Is it possible to list resulted papers by number of its citation in Google Scholar?

Tags: google-search, google-scholar

I use Google Scholar to search papers a lot. When I type in the key words, Google Scholar finds papers which contain those key words. I’m wondering, can Google Scholar sort these papers by their number of citation? If this is possible, then, the most top one could be the one which contains those key words and also has most number of citations. Is there such functionality for users to configure their searches?

Comment: I’m not sure this it’s what you are looking for, or if it works the way you need it to, but there is [Google Scholar Universal Gadget for Scientific Publication Citation Counting](http://code.google.com/p/citations-gadget/).

Comment: Thanks for reply. But after I checked the link, it seems that the gadget is for finding number of citations for a specific author only. What I am trying to do is to be able to list all related papers with the top one being the one with most number of citations. The resulted papers do not need to be belonged to the same author. Thanks,

Comment: There's another similar question: [How to sort Google Scholar search results by number of citations?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/20280/177684)